# Go import cycle not allowed

Tags: go

I'm new to `go`  and learning `go`. I want this kind of folder structure where **model** is database entity ,
**controller** is where the endpoint is and
**service** is where actual functionality happens.
(Issue is with the folder/package structure)

```
Course
    --- Course.controler.go
    --- Course.model.go
    --- course.service.go

Faculty
    --- Faculty.controller.go
    --- Faculty.model.go
    --- Faculty.service.go
```

1 Faculty can have 0..* Courses So I have implemented the foreign key here by **importing Faculty Package**

`course.model.go`

```
package course

import (
    "go-server/routes/faculty"

    "gorm.io/gorm"
)

type Course struct {
    gorm.Model
    Name        string          `json:"name"`
    Code        string          `json:"code" gorm:"unique;size:192"`
    Year        int             `json:"year"`
    Description string          `json:"description"`
    FacultyId   int             `json:"faculty"`
    Faculty     faculty.Faculty `gorm:"foreignKey:FacultyId"`
}
```

now if I implemented a function in `course.service.go` called `GetCoursesForFacultyID(id)`
I cant use it on `faculty.service` because of the import cycle. How can I overcome this issue ?

faculty -> course -> faculty

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to use a different folder structure

```
Course
    --- Course.controler.go
    --- Course.service.go

Faculty
    --- Faculty.controller.go
    --- Faculty.service.go

Models
    --- Course.model.go
    --- Faculty.model.go
```

or

```
School
    --- Course.controler.go
    --- Course.model.go
    --- Course.service.go
    --- Faculty.controller.go
    --- Faculty.model.go
    --- Faculty.service.go
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Is there anything other than changing folder structure ? dependency injection or

Comment: "Is there anything other than changing folder structure ?" No. Import cycles are simply **not** allowed.

Comment: Strictly speaking, in the general case, there may be a way that avoids changing the (existing) folder structure but does involve adding a *new* folder (i.e. package):  Make all types unexported and implement interfaces with accessors for the fields in a (new) package that is imported by both Course and Faculty.  But this may not be possible in this case given the involvement/needs of gorm (which may need the exported types; I haven't used gorm myself so am not certain).

Comment: @Volker So no dependency injection on Go lang

Comment: @Axios You certainly can have Dependency Injection in Go. What you cannot have are import cycles. But if _your_ definition of DI is "a certain layout in the filesystem, a certain paradigm (like MVC), a certain grouping, no excessive and unnecessary use of interfaces and Java/C#-style DI". Then yes. But if you want to program in exactly this way: Use Java or C#.

Comment: okay thank you everyone